# WSO2emm: Upload Application doesn't work

Tags: wso2-iot

I've just installed wso2emm and I have a problem with it when i try to upload an application from the Android Store (Play Store). I fill the tab "Package Name" with the value (for example com.fabernovel.ratp for the French RATP Application) and click on Next. When I did it nothing happened ... Have you an idea ? May be there is a specific configuration file ? Thanks for your help

Aurélien

Answer (score 0):

There is no such specific configuration file change to be done. Please refer to the WSO2 EMM [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Creating+an+Android+Application)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually enter details of your application. It does not extract data direly from the Play Store